# Show that for the $n$th roots of unity $w_0, ..., w_{n-1}$ where $n \gt 1$ that ...

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that for the $n$th roots of unity $w_0, ..., w_n$ where $n \gt 1$ that

$\sum _{j=0}^{n-1}w_j^k = 0$ for $1 \le k \le n-1$.

The book is suggesting that I use: $1 + z + z^2 + ... + z^n = \frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z}$ and let $z = w_1^k$ but I'm can't figure any relationship between the two.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Even if $k=0$? In $\mathbf C$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two corrections:

1. Where you wrote $w_0, ..., w_n,$ you should have written $w_0, ..., w_{n-1}.$
2. More importantly, the formula you wrote is not true for $k=0.$  The inequality should be $1 \le k \le n-1.$  (You can see that the sum is equal to $n$ if $k=0.)$

With those things said, if you use the fact that $$\omega_k=e^{2\pi ki/n},$$

you can see that the sum you want is the sum of a geometric progression, and you can apply the suggestion from your book.  (I've written $\omega,$ a lower-case Greek letter omega, instead of the letter $w,$ as you wrote it, since that's the common notation for this.)

Answer (score 0):

See that $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}w_j^k$ is really the same thing as $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}w_j$ since $w_j^k$ is equivalent to some other root of unity $w_p$.

See that $w_j=w_1^j$ thanks to Demoivre's formula.

It then becomes a geometric sum of the form $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}z^j=\frac{1-z^n}{1-z}$ where $z=w_1$.

See then that $1-w_1^n=1-1=0$ (recall what a root of unity is).

Thus, $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}w_j^k=0$ for any whole number $1\le k\le n-1$.  (a small note is that this is not true for non-integer $k$, nor is it true for $k=0$, which is obvious.)

Comment: `since w_j^k is equivalent to some other root of unity w_p` This needs elaborating more carefully. For example with $n=4,k=2$ the sum $1^2 + i^2 + (-1)^2 + (-i)^2 = 1 -1 -1 +1$ is not "*really the same thing*" as $1+i-1-i$ even though they happen to be both $0$, but that's part of what you are trying to prove.